# Got 'IOException: hostname was not verified', although given hostname (IP address) matches common name

Tags: java, android, ssl, okhttp

How is it possible that I get a `IOException: hostname was not verified` after I have successfully inserted my certificate, and use it as part of OKHttp's SSLFactory instance? I know that this is a common issue with self-signed certificates, but only if the name on the server, does not match the name on the certificate. In my case, the exception message shows me the address, and then the CN, and they DO match perfectly.

I solved the issue temporarily, by providing a super-permissive host verifier:

```
this.client.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        //TODO: Make this more restrictive
        return true;
    }
});
```

but it still feels weird. Can you perhaps tell me what could be causing this issue? Or, at least, what would be a more restrictive handler in your opinion? I guess, one that tries to extract the hostname from the session, and compare with the `hostname` param.

Update:
Here is the stack trace, as requested. For privacy reasons, I could not disclose any of the data, but keep in mind that hostname IP, and the CN match 1:1.

```
java.io.IOException: Hostname xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx not verified:
certificate: sha1/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=
DN: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx=#xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,CN=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,OU=xxxxxx,O=xxxxxx,L=xxxxxx,ST=xxxxxx,C=xx
subjectAltNames: []
at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:260)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:158)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:174)
at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:120)
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:131)
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:312)
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:235)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:262)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:219)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:192)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
```

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace and some more code.

Comment: @Jens added a stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hostname xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx not verified

It looks like you are connecting to an IP address.
The matching behavior for IP differs between implementation, but the check as defined for RFC2818 (https) requires the IP address to be in the subject alternative name section ([RFC2818, page 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#page-4)):

> In some cases, the URI is specified as an IP address rather than a
> hostname. In this case, the iPAddress subjectAltName must be present
> in the certificate and must exactly match the IP in the URI.

The actual behavior differs between implementations. Some accept the IP as CN, others not. Some implement the correct behavior to require the IP as type iPAddress while others expect it as type dNSName. So your better put it as CN and additionally in the subject alternative names section as iPAdress and dNSName :(

Comment: I think that's the reason